# Brute Force- c#

Tags: c#, textbox, brute-force

I tried to make simple brute force algorithm.It s working normal.But I was watching this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2xwficgRYk&feature=relmfu

(time 10:30) as you can see in textbox2 posibilities changes .But in my program.I create 1323 as a password and then when i click brute i waited 5 second and get 99999 in textbox2 and 1323 in textbox3.Why i cant see the flow of number in textbox2 like on video?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    int a, b;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) 
        {
            textBox2.Text = "" + i;
            if (a == i) textBox3.Text = "" + i; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a weird place to declare instance fields...

Comment: You need to refresh the text in the text box every time you change it, otherwise it won't show. not sure how that is done though

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with brute-force as opposed to handling UI updating properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the program in the video is running the brute force loop in a separate thread.

In your program the loop runs in the main thread, so as long as it's running there is no thread watching the message pump where all the user interface updates happen.

Whenever the `Text` property of the text box is changed there is a message dropped in the message queue that the text box needs to be redrawn to show the value, but the main thread is busy running the loop and won't act on the messages until the loop is done.

Answer (score 3):

In windows forms, there is a single thread for the user interface and all the code in code behind is processed on this thread too so while it's running your `for` loop, it's not re-drawing the changes in the screen.

The way you can get round this is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the processing on a separate thread and allow the user interface thread to re-draw the changes to the screen.

A couple of points about your code sample, you should declare your fields like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int a;
    private int b;

    ...
}
```

You should also give them more meaningful names!

Additionally, you should use the `.ToString()` method on int instead of concatenating it with an empty string to get the text value.

```
textBox2.Text = i.ToString();
```